# Is the Jordan Curve Theorem True for Curves on a Toroid

Tags: general-topology

I'm making a presentation on the Jordan Curve Theorem, and I want a counter-example. I think that the toroid is a great example, but I want to make sure that I'm correct.

Since the toroid has a hole in it, we could technically draw a curve that encloses this hole. Would the resulting curve satisfy the JCT? I don't think that it would, since you wouldn't end up with two distinct regions (like you would on, say, the 2-sphere). It seems to me like the hole allows you to get around the idea of dividing something into two components. Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: The Jordan Curve theorem's (and, I suppose, the Schoenflies theorem's) appropriate analogue on a torus is "either the curve bounds a disc, in which case it separates the torus into two connected components, or it doesn't, in which case its complement is one connected component, homeomorphic to the annulus $S^1 \times (-1,1)$."

Comment: So, does that mean the JCT as we ordinarily know it does not work on a toroid?

Comment: No. Indeed, you gave an example of the latter type in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the Jordan Curve theorem needs modifications if you were to implement it on (closed) surfaces other than the sphere. The [meridian or longitude curves](http://www.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/torus.with.axes.png) are examples of curves that do not split the torus into two connected components.

Here's a formulation that works for the torus (including Schoenflies-like statements on the torus):

Given a closed simple curve in the torus, if the curve bounds an embedded disc, then it separates the torus into two connected components; the non-disc component is homeomorphic to a topological space $X$ not depending on the chosen embedded curve. If it does not bound a disc, its complement is connected, and indeed homeomorphic to the open cylinder (or annulus, if you like) $S^1 \times (-1,1)$.

You can see a proof of this in chapter 2 of Rolfsen's book "Knots and Links". It takes some work, and assumes you already know the Schoenflies theorem for the sphere.

A sort of general JCT might be stated as follows: given a simple closed curve $K$ in a surface $\Sigma$, $K$ separates $\Sigma$ into at most two pieces, and it separates $\Sigma$ into two pieces if and only if $K$ is null-homotopic. In this case, $K$ actually bounds an embedded disc. (This still applied for the sphere - all curves in the sphere are null-homotopic.)

Comment: The JCT can be formulated as estated at the end of this answer for the sphere, the projective plane or the torus. But for other surfaces things become more delicate. For instance, a genus $2$ oriented surface is the connected sum of two tori, and the glueing circle separates but it is not nulhomotopic. The matter is that separation comes from the $1$-homology group, not from homotopy. The three distinguished surfaces have commutative fundamental group, hence it is the homology group.